# Java Round up the decimal to integer

Tags: java

```
    cyan = (white - (red / 255)) / white*100.0;
    magenta = (white - (green / 255)) / white*100.0;
    yellow = (white - (blue / 255)) / white*100.0;
    black = (1 - white)*100.0;
```

I get my program executed with the decimal number, how can I change to the integers and get the whole numbers??

Comment: Maybe you need `floor()` or `ceil()`. Have a look here  https://www.guru99.com/math-java.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to round up a decimal, you should use `(int) Math.ceil(x);` if you need to round to the biggest integer:

`System.out.println((int) Math.ceil(2.1)); // prints 3`

Otherwise you should use `Math.round(x)` which returns integer value closest to the nearest integer:

```
System.out.println(Math.round(2.1)); // prints 2
System.out.println(Math.round(2.7)); // prints 3
```

Comment: You're welcome! I'd be glad if you could this answer as accepted.  Thank you!